# Проблема с асинхронностью useState React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Всем привет. Пишу программу погодную на реакте и столкнулся бедой с хуком useState. а именно то что он асинхронен и дату которую я должен получить в state получается на первый клик сабмита null а на второй уже отрабатывает норм. Я написал некоторые функции и вызываю их в главной функции. Код немного сокращу чтобы не было лишней воды

```
const useForecast = () => {
    const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);
    
    // функция где я меняю state
    const gatherForecastData = async data => {
        const currentDay = await getCurrentDayForecast(data.consolidated_weather[0], data.title);
        const currentDayDetails = await getCurrentDayDetailedForecast(data.consolidated_weather[0]);
         
        await setForecast({ currentDay, currentDayDetails});
        setLoading(false);
    };
 
    // главная функция где вызываются другие функции
    const submitRequest = async location => {
        setLoading(true);
        setError(false);
 
        const response = await getWoeid(location);
        if (!response?.woeid) return;
 
        const data = await getForecastData(response.woeid);
        if (!data) return;
        
        gatherForecastData(data);
        console.log(data);
        // эта дата которая идет с api отрабатывает нормально
        console.log(forecast);
        // эта же дата только которая должна быть в state выдает null
    };
```

Как тут избавиться от этой ошибки?

Comment: gatherForecastData  может возвращать данные не сохраняя в стейте, или объеденить эти 2 функции и сохранять стейт в конце submitRequest. Так же можно отслеживать стейт в useEffect

Comment: @KonstantinModin я многое что перепробовал, стейт все равно не успевает измениться (или что то вроде того), а useEffect нельзя использовать внутри функций

Comment: правильное поведение - на момент помещения функции console.log() в стек, значение `forecast = null`
пользуйте useEffect на верхнем уровне (вне функций)

Answer (score 0):

`setState` - [асинхронная функция](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)

Это значит, что после вызова `setForecast` значение `forecast` изменится не сразу и `console.log` будет возвращать старое значение.

Чтобы дождаться изменения значения `forecast` нужно использовать `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(forecast);
}, [forecast]);
```

Comment: да, я понимаю это, но как мне к примеру использовать useEffect если gatherForecastData, где стейт меняется, вызывается в submitRequest? я попросту никак не могу связать с useEffect

Comment: useEffect сам вызовется, когда значение forecast изменится

Answer (score 0):

```
const useForecast = () => {
const [forecast, setForecast] = useState(null);
console.log(forecast) после ререндера будет новое значение

useEffect(() => {
   если надо что то сделать после ререндера
}, [forecast])

// функция где ты просто дастаеш данные
const gatherForecastData = async data => {
    const currentDay = await something
    const currentDayDetails = await something2
     
    return { currentDay, currentDayDetails }
};

// главная функция где вызываются другие функции
const submitRequest = async location => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(false);

    const response = await getWoeid(location);
    if (!response?.woeid) return;

    const data = await getForecastData(response.woeid);
    if (!data) return;
    
    const res = await gatherForecastData(data);
    setForecast(res);
    // если нужен именно по каким то причинам forecast то как и советовали useEffect
    // если просто значение то на данный момент это все еще **res**
    setLoading(false);
};
```